# Searching tweets published from Delicious with Twitter API

Tags: twitter, delicious-api

I am a new user in StackOverflow. I am developing a tool.

My problem is that I am trying get tweets published from Delicious ("X minutes ago via Delicious").

In Twitter API Documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search), I can see:

> Originating from an application:
>   http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:tweetie

I am copy & paste "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:tweetie" in web navigator. The example from Twitter API don't work!!! :S

However, I am trying others search applications, and WORK:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:TweetDeck
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:twitterfeed
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:ping.fm
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:web
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:SocialOomph
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:tumblr
```

But when I try to search for Delicious, don't work:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:Delicious
```

Why? I am try next, and don't work:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:del.icio.us
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:icio.us
```

Exists solution to http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=landing+source:Delicious?

I am try to access to Twitter API IRC, but don't work... :S

Thank you very much, and I sorry my bad English. Regards! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `landing+source:Delicious` there are no search results because there frankly aren't any recent tweets containing "landing" that were tweeted using Delicious.

The other source applications contain results because people *have* been tweeting "landing" using other apps, as you've noted.

But `source:Delicious` does work; try searching for other terms, like `food+source:Delicious` or `happy+source:Delicious` and you should see results.

Comment: Ohh, thank you! :)

And... do you know some method for get all tweets from Delicious, because only "source:Delicious" don't work... :S

In Twitter API documentation don't found info:
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search

Thank you very much!